# How do I access only the value from the object returned in the variable through a query?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

**array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#471 (1) { ["COUNT(*)"]=> int(209) } }**
This is the value I am getting in a variable.
When I am trying to print this it says **string cant be converted**.
From the controller when I pass this variable it doesn't print at the blade page.
I know this might be an easy solution but I am not getting on the answer on the internet for this one.

```
$val = DB::select('select count(*) from stud where (Select sum(eng+french+german)/3 >3.5)');
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You should use an alias for "count(*)", eg `SELECT count(*) AS mycount FROM ..`, then you can access it like `$val[0]->mycount`

Comment: It worked, thanks but I am passing an array from the controller and doing an alert in blade within the script tag so it's showing the correct data, but when I try to run it in a loop it prints nothing, ` var st_fail = @json($st_fail); var locs = @json($locs); ` BUT this loop is not working ` for (let i = 0; i < locs.length; i++) { [locs[i],st_pass[i],st_fail[i]] }` Any help would be appreciated @Honk der Hase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$count = DB::table('stud')
    ->whereRaw('((eng + french + german) / 3) > 3.5')
    ->count();
```

Comment: yeah this can also be done but I am passing an array from the controller and doing an alert in blade within the script tag so it's showing the correct data, but when I try to run it in a loop it prints nothing, ` var st_fail = @json($st_fail);
      var locs = @json($locs); `  BUT this loop is not working ` for (let i = 0; i < locs.length; i++) {
            [locs[i],st_pass[i],st_fail[i]]
      }`
Any help would be appreciated @Bob

Comment: Provide code of controller and blade template, because I do not understand the problem